# Trigger Modal Close button

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, sandbox, react-bootstrap4-modal

I would like some assistance executing onHide event function which would setShow state to false when Close Button inside the Modal component is clicked.

[image: X next to Payment Transaction Notification works but Close doesn't]

Demo sandbox found here: [Sandbox](https://tgmct.csb.app/)

*I've temporarily bypassed submitHandler for debugging the modal only, line 71 will trigger the modal in a normal scenario*

Do note Close is meant to `window.close()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to add a new callback (e.g: `buttonClose`) for your modal's **Close** button.

```
<Button
    variant="secondary"
    {...props}
    onClick={() => props.buttonClose()}
    className="text-center"
>
Close
</Button>
```

And invoke it from your `Step` Component.

```
<SuccessModal
    ref={props.superModalElement}
    show={show}
    onHide={handleClose}
    buttonClose={handleClose}
/>
```

Working demo at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-water-w6yod).